# After running my project few times I'm getting error: Could not resolve COM reference "f8937e53-d444-4e71-9275-35b64210cc3b" what's that?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autoit-c#-wrapper

This is the full error:

```
Error   1   Could not resolve COM reference "f8937e53-d444-4e71-9275-35b64210cc3b" version 1.0. The specified image file did not contain a resource section. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070714)   UsingAutoIt
```

Never had it before google didn't find anything with this reference long number and letters.

This is my form1 complete code not that long. Maybe the DllImport make the problem ? But it didn't before. Strange error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using AutoItX3Lib;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace UsingAutoIt
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);


        static AutoItX3Lib.AutoItX3Class au3;
        static Thread thread;
        static bool threadshouldexecute = true;
        static int i = 0;
        string processName = "GameCapture";
        string existingProcessName = "Game Capture HD";
        string processFileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Elgato\GameCapture\GameCapture.exe";
        IntPtr windowHandle;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            au3 = new AutoItX3Lib.AutoItX3Class();
            au3.AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode", 4);

            if (au3.WinExists(existingProcessName, "") == 0) // Window not found
            {
                int processId = au3.Run(processFileName, "", au3.SW_SHOW);
                BringToFront(processId);
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                au3.MouseClick("LEFT", 358, 913, 1, -1);

            }
            else
            {
                Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
                BringToFront(processes[0].Id);
                au3.MouseClick("LEFT", 358, 913, 1, -1);
            }
        }

        public static void BringToFront(int processId)
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
            IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;

            if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
                return;

            SetForegroundWindow(handle);
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer t1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            t1.Interval = 50;
            t1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            //t1.Enabled = true;
            t1.Enabled = false;
        }

        public static Point GetMousePosition()
        {
            var position = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
            return new Point(position.X, position.Y);
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = string.Format("X={0}, Y={1}", GetMousePosition().X, GetMousePosition().Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed it now but it's not a solution. The problem is that on my project I added as reference the dll file AutoItX3Lib. But to do that I had first to register using regsrv32 only after register it I could add as reference the dll file. Then in my project in this dll file properties I had to change the property Embed Interop Types to false. And it was working fine until now. Now what I did was changing this property Embed Interop Types to true then to false again and now the error is gone.

Comment: But still I can't figure out what and why cause this error first time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But to do that I had first to register using regsrv32 only after register it I could add as reference the dll file.

This is normal, Visual Studio stores the guid of the type library in the project file.  A type library is a description of the types exported by the COM component.  Very similar to metadata in a .NET assembly.  Finding the library back from the "f8937e53-d444-4e71-9275-35b64210cc3b" guid in the project file requires Visual Studio to look in the registry, HKCR\TypeLib key.  It is not going to be there until *after* the COM component is registered.  Yes, Regsvr32.exe, in general it is better to use the component's installer.

> I had to change the property Embed Interop Types to false

That is because you used `AutoItX3Lib.AutoItX3Class` in your source code.  This is a synthetic class that is generated from the type library, it makes COM components that implement multiple interfaces a bit easier to use.  Such a synthetic class however cannot be embedded, that's why you had to set the property to *false*.  The simple workaround for that is to omit "Class" from the type name so you only use the interface.  Fix:

```
    static AutoItX3Lib.AutoItX3 au3;
    ....
    au3 = new AutoItX3Lib.AutoItX3();
```

Comment: while working in my project, suddenly this error showed up on code build. I simply cleaned solution and project, then I restarted visual studio. the error disappeared.